# Determine which protocol is being used over USB?

Tags: storage, usb-storage, thunderbolt, nvme, usb-3.1-type-c

How can I see which protocol is being used over USB?

I would like to verify that NVMe is being used over Thunderbolt 3/USB 3.

It behaves as the NVMe enclosure advertised–I could probably boot off this thing and not notice–but where can I see this detailed?

I can check in macOS or Windows, but not Linux at the moment.

In System Profiler the device appears under Storage with the Protocol *USB*, and nothing more. Seems vague.

[Image of System Profiler showing an NVMe USB3 enclosure hosting an M.2. NVMe device appearing to use the USB protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Pjw.png)

It doesn't appear under the NVMe section.

In Windows, I also get NVMe access times and IOPs, but see a SAS storage controller appear in Device Manager when plugged in. [hands up shrugging "iono" emoji]

Comment: NVMe works over PCIe, so check if your device shows up as PCIe device over Thunderbolt. If it shows up as an USB device, then it uses an USB storage protocol. Though "NVMe access times" shouldn't matter - you've connected up the thing through Thunderbolt/USB, so no matter what protocol is used, data transfer speed is determined by that connection.

Comment: Hi @dirkt, only the internal drive appears there. The beauty of the new port is that it should provide up to four direct PCIe lanes to the CPU, which is why dedicated GPUs can even be run through them. I think it actually is running as NVMe, but just thought I'd ask the question out of curiosity. On a side note, I'm never much concerned about transfer rates with storage, and always about access times, as I view them as forms of memory when pretending to be a CPU. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sPoU.png

Comment: @dirkt It turned out to be using SCSI over USB. It's much faster than SATA but obviously not as fast as a true NVMe lane.

Comment: Being downvoted is not cool, but it doesn't make insults acceptable.

Comment: @gronostaj it’s the only recourse. Why is it beneficial to have anonymous Q&A?

Comment: Feel free to ask this question on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/).

Comment: Ad money. That’s the main reason @gronostaj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought a new cable and even though it is three feet long I get microseconds access times, apparently this all done with a SCSI-like device running on USB.

I will take it!